# sidekiq executes jobs when called in rails console, but not in app controller

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Thanks for reading, I'm new to Sidekiq -- and hope that this is a simple configuration issue I'm missing. 
Anyhoo --

Redis is up locally. Foreman loads rails and sidekiq's sinatra app. 
I call a sidekiq method in the rails console- and it executes immediately (though is not registered in the dashboard at  localhost/sidekiq ... but job is processed and email is sent).

I call the same method in the controller, within the app, and the job enqueues, but never executes.
So -- what am I doin wrong?

here's some code!

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq  2>&1 | logger -t sidekiq
```

config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 5)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { size: 1 }
  end
end
```

config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/12' }
end
```

I call

```
DonationMailerWorker.perform_async(Donation.last.id)
```

in the console. and get a nice sidekiq return id:
"5725654a3b202d8ea5fc2ef3"
and recieve some email shortly thereafter. 
hurray!

BUT -- 
I call the SAME METHOD in the controller
Sidekiq adds the job to the default queue, shown in the dashboard UI, but never executes it.

Also -- in the controller -- if I call the method synchronously -- ala

```
DonationMailerWorker.new.perform(Donation.last.id)
```

It DOES execute correctly and immediately.

So -- people of greater sidekiq capability -- 
Please help.

And -- more stats re: my dev env -->
ruby 2.0.0
rails 4.1.5
mailgun email via smtp

Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain the sidekiq process is running? Like you can do ps aux | grep sidekiq and see the running process?

Comment: Thanks @JulioGMedina --  yes, registering as running -- terminal output in next comment

Comment: `AviFoxi         49181   0.0  0.0  2441972    564 s000  S+    7:51PM   0:00.00 logger -t sidekiq
AviFoxi         49180   0.0  2.2  3286472 186604 s000  S+    7:51PM   0:08.56 sidekiq 3.3.3 r4r_up_from_models_redo [0 of 25 busy]  
AviFoxi         49179   0.0  0.0  2442584    948 s000  S+    7:51PM   0:00.00 sh -c /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner -d '/Users/AviFoxi/Desktop/active_projects/r4r_up_from_models_redo' -p -- bundle exec sidekiq  2>&1 | logger -t sidekiq 
AviFoxi         49370   0.0  0.0  2441988    676 s002  S+    7:52PM   0:00.01 grep sidekiq`